# working on api call and getting data back in json format

Tags: coldfusion, asp.net-web-api, sendgrid

I have a question regarding sending a Web API call to sendgrid:

The following documentation is used to retrieve advanced stats:

http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/statistics_advanced.html

In the "Call" section, the following has been mentioned:

```
POST    https://api.sendgrid.com/api/stats.getAdvanced.json
POST Data   api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&start_date=2013-01-01&end_date=2013-01-02&data_type=global
```

I understand that I need to use cfhttp for the Web API call and I should be 
mentioning `"https://api.sendgrid.com/api/stats.getAdvanced.json"` in the url parameter
of the `cfhttp` tag.

Where do I need to mention api_user and api_key portion? I understand that I will have
to mention my sendgrid's account username and password here.

For Explanation Purpose let's consider the following dummy values for:

```
api_user = stack

api_key = 123456
```

Please let me know. I am trying to send an API call an get the data back in JSON format.

Thanks

**ATTEMPT #1**

I am using the following code:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.sendgrid.com/api/stats.getAdvanced.json" method="POST" result="returnStruct">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_user" value="stack" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_key" value="123456" type="formfield">
    <!--- <cfhttpparam name="days" value="5" type="formfield">  --->
    <cfhttpparam name="start_date" value="2013-12-06" type="formfield"> 
    <!--- <cfhttpparam name="end_date" value="2013-12-09" type="formfield"> --->

</cfhttp>


<cfdump var="#returnStruct#">
```

I am getting the following error in the form of Structure. Am I doing something wrong above? Please check my code below.

```
Charset     [empty string]
ErrorDetail     [empty string]
Filecontent     {"error": "error in data_type: data_type is required"}
Header  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html Connection: close Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2013 06:21:19 GMT Server: nginx/1.4.2
Mimetype    text/html
Responseheader  
struct
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 10 Dec 2013 06:21:19 GMT
Explanation     Bad Request
Http_Version    HTTP/1.1
Server  nginx/1.4.2
Status_Code     400
Statuscode  400 Bad Request
Text    YES
```

I am wondering, which `data_type` it is  referring to, as the documentation doesn't talks about it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would use [`<cfhttpparam>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html) for each of the keys:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.sendgrid.com/api/stats.getAdvanced.json" method="POST">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_user" value="some_username_goes_here" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_key" value="some_api_key_goes_here" type="formfield">
    ...more params...
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please check my error that I mentioned under "Attempt #1" section of my original post. Thanks

Comment: The documentation does talk about it "data_type"--it's the first parameter in the documentation link you posted. It's a required parameter, so that explains the error you're receiving.

Comment: @jack did you find your solution please share... Thanks